# How to shorten similar Python import statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I've a **large custom project package** for `Digital-Assistant` program in Python.
In order to use several files in other sub-packages of same lib, I've to import many files having **same sub-path** in the import statement, which makes it look redundant.

##### For example :

```
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.web_bots.google_bot import searchGoogle
from mylibs.AI.CV import *
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.web_bots.social_media_connect import wa_pag
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.languages import access_dictionary
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.digital_assistant import speech_to_text
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.user_interface import *
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.web_bots.social_media_connect import *
from mylibs.master_lib.data_science.data_analytics import *
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.webAppsOC import *
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.device_controller import *
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.computer_graphics import *
from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.desktopAppsFiles import *
from mylibs.AI.NLP import *
```

In the above snippet, the statement '**mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant**' is common to many imports. `(similar to huge libraries like Django, Tensorflow, etc)`

> I guess giving short names to libs isn't an option, as its obvious all heavy packages prefer detailed nomenclatures.

###### Is there any way to give an alternative small name to those big identical import sub-paths ?

Comment: Having such a deeply nested tree of packages is uncommon in Python. I'd expect `digital_assistant` to be a top-level package.

Comment: Actually, the scenario is different here, the package contains AI stuffs too, which are part of AI digital assistant project, that digital_assistant sub-package is just a part of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These situations occur in case of huge projects like `Semi-Detached` and `Embedded` types of projects according to [`COCOMO Model`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/software-engineering-cocomo-model/)

#### Method 1

Make use of `exec` function, `f-strings` and `for loop` to achieve this

> This method is useful in case of large amount of imports which has no desire to maintain readability

```
for module in ["web_bots.google_bot import searchgoogle", "web_bots.social_media_connect import wa_pag", "languages import access_dictionary", "digital_assistant import speech_to_text","user_interface import *", "web_bots.social_media_connect import *", "webappsopenclose import *"]:
    exec(f"from mylibs.master_lib.digital_assistant.{module}")

for module in [".data_science.data_analytics import *", ".device_controller import *", ".artificial_intelligence.cv.computer_graphics import *"]:
    exec(f"from mylibs.master_lib.{module}")
```

#### Method 2

> In case you want to maintain the readability of program
> Make use of `exec` function along with `f-strings` to alter length of big imports

```
MM, DA = "from mylibs.master_lib", "digital_assistant"
exec(f"{MM}.{DA}.web_bots.google_bot import searchgoogle")
exec(f"{MM}.{DA}.web_bots.social_media_connect import wa_pag")
exec(f"{MM}.{DA}.languages import access_dictionary")
exec(f"{MM}.{DA}.digital_assistant import speech_to_text")
exec(f"{MM}.{DA}.user_interface import *")
exec(f"{MM}.{DA}.web_bots.social_media_connect import *")
exec(f"{MM}.{DA}.webappsopenclose import *")
exec(f"{MM}.data_science.data_analytics import *")
exec(f"{MM}.device_controller import *")
exec(f"{MM}.artificial_intelligence.cv.computer_graphics import *")
```

#### Method 3

You can also use `importlib`

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module(".Add_Ons", "MyLibs.GrandCollection.DS.Strings")
```

But this method is feasible in importing modules instead of functions or constants directly.